# Cocos2D file implementation into UIKit app?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, implementation

I literally have been pulling my hair out over this for a few days now. I am simply trying to implement Cocos2D into my UIKit app but I am not sure which files I need. I know to download it from http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/ so I did, I open up the cocos2d-ios .xcodeproj but I have absolutely no idea **which** files to drag into my to properly implement it in my app.

I really need help with this!!!!

Thanks,
MyApps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the entire cocos2D library into your project (all the files from the unarchived download).

You can then #import "cocos2D.h" into your view controller and assign your EAGLView (create one in the view controller if your project doesn't have one already) to cocos2D 
(eg: [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setOpenGLView: glView];)

I know it's a bit backward, but it might be easier to create a template cocos2D project and from there migrate your existing files to the new project (your mileage may vary depending on how complex your existing project/build is).

Comment: Thanks for info. When you say cocos2d library, which folders are you talking about in the official cocos2d download? There is a lot and I want to make sure I get it right. When I download it, I go to finder and I see all the folders there for cocos2d but I am unsure if which in particular.

Comment: The following folders are the ones of interest:
'cocos2d', 'CocosDenshion', 'cocoslive', 'experimental', 'external'.

Give it a try, but again don't be afraid to make a template project & copy your stuff over if you are having a hard time with this (you are not the first nor will you be the last!)

Here's a discussion at the cocos2d forums over nearly the same issue (someone wants to upgrade the version of cocos2d they are using in their project, requires copying the cocos2d files into an existing project) could be helpful:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/16661

Comment: Ok this is exactly what I did. DL'ed the latest cocos2d. I selected those 5 folders you mentioned. Dragged them into my project folder (through finder). Then once they were in my project's folder, I dragged them into my project (Xcode 4). I not selected 'copy to group destination target'. Also before I did all this I cleaned my project. Now I get 3 errors and 4 warnings.
Errors:
1. Box2D/Collision/b2BroadPhase.h file not found in b2BroadPhase.cpp
2. Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2CircleShape.h file not found in b2CircleShape.cpp
3. Box2D/Collision/b2Collision.h file not found in b2CollideCircle.cpp

Comment: 2nd post (1st post too long). I don't actually need Box2D, I just need Cocos2D so how would I just get rid of these errors and all Box2D files since I do not need it?
Also I get a warning 4 times that says: Warning: Multiple build commands for output files 'CMakeLists.txt' and 'ReadMe.txt'. I am guessing these warnings relate to Cocos2D so how would I fix those?

Comment: 3rd post (update): I deleted the Box2D/Chipmunk folders in the external file in both Xcode and finder. I still get 1 error: vorbis/ivorbiscodec.h file not found in ivorbisfile_example.c.
How would I fix this?

Comment: Hmm. Apologies on the late response! The ivorbiscodec.h file is located in Extras/Tremor in the cocos2d folder. Double check that folder is in the project. I'll try recreating what you're doing & see if I have any luck (it's been a while since I implanted cocos2d into an existing project so I might be giving some out-of-date advice but try the above & see if it works).

Comment: Whoops! I never said to add "Extras" in the first place! My bad, add it and try again :P

Comment: Haha, I am confused now. So now which files are you saying to add exactly? What overall files do I need now, now that you know my situation!